# How to get Image URLs of Google search in android

Tags: android, google-custom-search

I need to show Google search images in list view, Google search API is deprecated and I heard that custom google search will help, But That is not working I tried This link
https://fbombmedia.com/set-google-custom-search-api-app/
Can anyone help
Thanks